# Error: Program type already present: com.google.auto.value.AutoValue$Builder

Tags: java, android

if I use the emulator the program work fine, but when I try to create one release, the error appear...**Error: Program type already present: com.google.auto.value.AutoValue$Builder**

the only code that I have modify is the Firebase code, but the emulator works.

how can find which is the module are repeated?

this is my grandle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
}
// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

dependencies {
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion version_setup_compileSdk
    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
        applicationId "com.bandweb.myrecipesmaker"
        minSdkVersion version_setup_minSdk
        //targetSdkVersion 27
        //versionCode 1
        //versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def value = 0

        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
            value = 1
        }

        def versionMajor = versionProps['VERSION_MAJOR'].toInteger()
        def versionMinor = versionProps['VERSION_MINOR'].toInteger()
        def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
        def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        def versionNumber = versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
        println "VERSION_CODE incremented to " + value

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.bandweb.myrecipesmaker"
            versionCode versionNumber
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild}) Release"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            multiDexEnabled true //important
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_TEST_BUILD", "false"
            buildConfigField "String[]", "APPLICATION_LANGUAGES", "${getUsedAndroidLanguages()}"
        }

        // If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
        // you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
        // through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
        // but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
        // However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
        // added during execution.
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS_ENABLED", 'true'
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS_ENABLED", 'false'
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
//configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }

dependencies {
    //def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha11"
    def nav_version = "1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${version_library_appcompat}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${version_library_appcompat}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${version_library_appcompat}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${version_library_appcompat}"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${version_library_appcompat}"
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/super-csv-2.4.0.jar')
    // Check for v11.4.2 or higher

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.7'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
 //   implementation files('libs/commons-csv-1.6.jar')

    // Joda-time
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
    // Add dependency
    //implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'

    // Dependencies for the REST API example
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev139-1.22.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'me.tankery.lib:permission-requester:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:28.0.0.0'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7-simplemenu:28.0.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    //implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:2.0.0-rc7'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    // Tool libraries
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${version_library_butterknife}"
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$version_plugin_kotlin"
    }
    implementation('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:2.13.0'

    // fragment util
    //implementation 'com.blankj:utilcode:1.22.10'

    // Glide image library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
//    implementation ('com.github.worker8:tourguide:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
//        transitive=true
//    }
//    implementation 'com.github.wangjiegulu:rfab:2.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.rm:rmswitch:1.2.2'

    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${version_library_butterknife}"
    //AutoValue
    compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$autoValueVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$autoValueVersion"

    //annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:auto-parcel:1.0.3'
    //compileOnly 'com.jakewharton.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.5'
   // annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
    //implementation 'com.github.Zhuinden:simple-stack:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // Processors
    def anpros = ["com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${version_library_butterknife}"]
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    for (anpro in anpros) {
        if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
            kapt anpro
        } else {
            annotationProcessor anpro
        }
    }
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
}
```